# Opensearch - Reindex periodically using Query DSL

Tags: querydsl, opensearch, reindex

I need to reindex data periodically like every 1 hour using a custom Query DSL.

I reindex a subset of documents, i use an ingest pipeline and a custom script to update the new index.

It looks like that (with changed values):

```js
POST _reindex?wait_for_completion=false
{
  "source": {
    "index": "index",
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "filter": {
            "terms": {
                "Domain.keyword":  ["Custom.Value0", "Custom.Value1", "Custom.Value2"]
            }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new-index-clean",
    "pipeline": "my-pipeline"
  },
  "script": {
      "lang": "painless",
      "source": "if (!ctx._source.containsKey(\"Field\") || ctx._source.Field == null) {ctx._source.Field = ctx._index}"
    }
}
```

I installed Job Scheduler on my Opensearch instance and i saw that you can create custom plugins to run your jobs but i can't install custom plugins and i can't find documentation on how to use it otherwise.

I tried Rollups or Transorm job but i don't have the option i need for my reindex.

Comment: When you're dealing with periodic execution of tasks like the one you've described the use of custom plugins isn't an option. You might consider using external tools or services that can schedule and execute these jobs. (example send request for reindexing in crontab on linux)

Comment: Okay, it's what i'm going to do, thanks for the answer